# Is there a way to use styled components / JSX as marker elements?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Marker = styled.div`...`
const MarkerIcon = styled.svg`...`

const element = (
  <Marker>
    <MarkerIcon />
  </Marker>
)

new mapboxgl.Marker(element)
  .setLngLat([...])
  .addTo(map)
```

Is this possible, or do you *have* to use document.createelement?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:

```
const marker = document.createElement('div')

new mapboxgl.Marker(marker)
  .setLngLat([...])
  .addTo(map)

ReactDOM.render(<Marker />, marker)
```